# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, win2d

On Windows 10 I'm developing a universal app. I have a project targeting from build 10240 to the Anniversary Edition(14393). I'm using the nuget Win2d.uwp and whilst developing the app in debug and release everything works fine. I can generate a Store package, deploy it through  HockeyApp and it work just fine. When I upload it to the store, and wait until it has been approved, download it, and start to use it, as soon as I draw a shadow in some controls using Win2d.uwp
and this code:

```
 public static void InitializeDropShadow(UIElement shadowHost, UIElement shadowTarget, Color color, ShadowPosition position)
    {
        var offset = GetOffset(position);

        var hostVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(shadowHost);
        var compositor = hostVisual.Compositor;

        // Create a drop shadow
        var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
        dropShadow.Color = Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.B, color.G, color.R);
        dropShadow.BlurRadius = 25.0f;
        dropShadow.Offset = offset;
        // Associate the shape of the shadow with the shape of the target element
        // dropShadow.Mask = shadowTarget.GetAlphaMask();

        // Create a Visual to hold the shadow
        var shadowVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        shadowVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

        // Add the shadow as a child of the host in the visual tree
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(shadowHost, shadowVisual);

        // Make sure size of shadow host and shadow visual always stay in sync
        var bindSizeAnimation = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("hostVisual.Size");
        bindSizeAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("hostVisual", hostVisual);

        shadowVisual.StartAnimation("Size", bindSizeAnimation);
    }

    private static Vector3 GetOffset(ShadowPosition position)
    {
        var result = new Vector3();
        switch (position)
        {
            case ShadowPosition.Center:
                result = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.Top:
                result = new Vector3(0, -SHADOW_OFFSET, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.Left:
                result = new Vector3(-SHADOW_OFFSET, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.Right:
                result = new Vector3(SHADOW_OFFSET, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.Bottom:
                result = new Vector3(0, SHADOW_OFFSET, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.TopLeft:
                result = new Vector3(-SHADOW_OFFSET, -SHADOW_OFFSET, 0);
                break;
            case ShadowPosition.BottomRight:
                result = new Vector3(SHADOW_OFFSET, SHADOW_OFFSET, 0);
                break;
            default:
                result = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                break;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

it breaks miserably and throw this exception breaking the whole app:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Windows.UI.Composition.DropShadow.put_Offset(System.Numerics.Vector3)'.
```

It only happens from the STORE version and I'm not compiling it with .Net Native. Any Ideas?

Comment: DropShadow was added in 10.0.14393.0 and is not available in 10240.  So at least you targeted it wrong.  And will go wrong with this exception if you are not running on 14393.  Or, I'd imagine, using the package built by the Store taking your 10240 claim serious.